# MPI scatterv gatherv

Tags: c++, mpi

In the (semplified) code below, I have a class whose first member is a pointer to pointers (a dynamic matrix), I want to know how to use scatterv and gatherv. My target is to split the matrix "horizontally" using the pointers to the rows.

class:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Mat{

private:

int **m;
unsigned cols;
unsigned rows;

void allocate_mem(int ***ptr, unsigned r, unsigned c){
    *ptr = new int *[r];
    (*ptr)[0] = new int[r*c];
    for(unsigned i = 1; i < r; i++)
        (*ptr)[i] = (*ptr)[0] + i*c;
}

public:

Mat(){
    rows = 1;
    cols = 1;
    allocate_mem(&m, 1, 1);
    m[0][0] = 0;
}

Mat(unsigned n_rows, unsigned n_cols){
    rows = n_rows;
    cols = n_cols;
    allocate_mem(&m, rows, cols);
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for(unsigned j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                m[i][j] = i+j;
}

Mat &operator=(const Mat &mrx){
    int **new_ptr = NULL;
    allocate_mem(&new_ptr, mrx.rows, mrx.cols);
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mrx.rows; i++)
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < mrx.cols; j++)
            new_ptr[i][j] = mrx[i][j];
    delete[] m[0];
    delete[] m;
    m = new_ptr;
    rows = mrx.rows;
    cols = mrx.cols;
    return *this;
}

const int *operator[](unsigned n) const{
    return m[n];
}

void create_output(){
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < cols; i++){
        for(unsigned j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

~Mat(){
    delete[] m[0];
    delete[] m;
}

};
```

main:

```
#include "Mat.cpp"
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

int rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
int p;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p);

Mat m;

if(rank==0){
    m = Mat(10,10);
    cout << "First:" << endl;
    m.create_output();
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

//MPI_Scatterv();

//MPI_Gatherv();

if(rank==0){
    cout << "Second:" << endl;
    m.create_output();
}

MPI_Finalize();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You need contiguous memory to send with scatter and receive with gather. Dynamic matrix does not satisfy this requirement. Since all rows in matrix has equal length you can allocate one block of memory (M * N * sizeof(int)) bytes size. And implement accessing i-th row as `&m[i*N]`. Then you can use scatter and gather on `m`.

Comment: Can I do what scatter and gather do manually or it's a thing to never do?

Comment: You can use `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` to implement scatter-gather functionality yourself, but unless you're willing to use contiguous momory blocks it will use many more messages; and it will increase complexity of your application. So, I would never do that if I could use scatter-gather. I even think it would be better to copy all data into contiguous block of memory and then scatter it or gather into contiguous block of memory and copy to dynamic matrix than taking `MPI_Recv`/`MPI_Send` approach.

Comment: In @Wellen 's case, the matrix seems to be allocated on contiguous memory : `(*ptr)[0] = new int[r*c];`. The right argument for `MPI_Scatter` may be `&m[0][0]`.

Comment: Well, what I need is not to scatter the elements of the matrix, but the rows of the matrix (for example if I have a matrix of 5 rows and 2 processors I need to assign the first 3 rows to processor1 and the other 2 rows to processor2)... I need to scatter the list of pointers "pointed" by the head pointer **m